# Caption of 3 figures correctly

Tags: captions, floatrow

How do i get the figure caption as i have them in the following picture?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
10pt,
twocolumn,
%draft,
leqno,
%fleqn
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \subfigure[primitiv]{\rule{1cm}{2cm}}
        \subfigure[basisflächenzentriert]{\rule{1cm}{2cm}}
        \captionof{figure}{monoklin}
        \label{fig:monoklin}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \subfigure[primitiv]{\rule{1cm}{2cm}}
        \captionof{figure}{triklin}
        \label{fig:triklin}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot i tryed subfigure and floatrow but i cant get my wantet result

Answer (score 1):

- `subfigure` is obsolete package. It is replaced by `subfig`
- Captions are to large that three image can be fit nicely in column width. Can you consider to have image over both column?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn, leqno]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=24mm, width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio}%
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\captionsetup{skip=-1ex}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XXX @{}}
\subfloat[primitiv]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
&
\subfloat[basisflächen\-zentriert]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
&    
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \\
\multicolumn{2}
            {p{0.6\hsize}}
            {\caption{monoklin}
             \label{fig:monoklin}
            }
&
    \caption{triklin}
    \label{fig:triklin}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- in case that you agree with second item, than replace in above MWE `fig` with  `figure*` float environment. With it yo will obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subcaption` (with `[t]` alignment). I strongly suggest using `figure*` for spanning the two columns. Three images in a column will be very narrow, leading to awkward subcaption.

```latex
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  10pt,
  twocolumn,
  %draft,
  leqno,
  %fleqn
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% let TeX compute the spaces

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{}}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{primitiv}
  \end{subfigure}
&
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{basisflächenzentriert}
  \end{subfigure}
&
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.6\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}
    \caption{monoklin}\label{fig:monoklin}
    \end{minipage}%
  }
&
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \caption{triklin}\label{fig:triklin}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tabular*}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]